# how do i make it so it checks specific element first in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

Using the for loop, how do i make it so it checks element (working 2) then working 1 if its empty?

At the moment, this code checks the first element then second element and so on. 
What i'm trying to do is prioritize other element first. In this case "working 2" element.

```js
paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working1,.working2'));
let partnumber = 0
for(const para of paras) {
  partnumber++
  if(para.innerHTML === '') {
     para.innerHTML = partnumber;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="machine1" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine2" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine3" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine4" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine5" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine6" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine7" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine8" class="working2"></p>
```

Actual Results - Checks if the elements (working 1) is empty, else it checks element (working2).
Expected Results - Checks if the elements (working 2) is empty, else it checks element (working1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create ".working2" and ".working1" arrays seperate, and then concat them by adding .working2 items first:

```
var working1 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working1'));
var working2 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working2'));

var paras = working2.concat(working1);
let partnumber = 0
for(const para of paras) {
  partnumber++
  if(para.innerHTML === '') {
     para.innerHTML = partnumber;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort `working2` elements before `working1` elements in the array:

```js
const paras1 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working1'));
const paras2 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working2'));
const paras = paras2.concat(paras1);
let partnumber = 0
for(const para of paras) {
  partnumber++
  if(para.innerHTML === '') {
     para.innerHTML = partnumber;
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<p id="machine1" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine2" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine3" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine4" class="working1"></p>
<p id="machine5" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine6" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine7" class="working2"></p>
<p id="machine8" class="working2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort it based on a particular category(in this case class name), we have to first define the sort order and then sort the `paras` based on that -

```
//sort order, this can be helpful if you have multiple classes
let sortOrder = ['working2', 'working1'];
let sortedParas = [];
let paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working1,.working2'));

sortOrder.forEach(order => {
    paras.forEach(para => {
      if(para.classList.contains(order)){
                sortedParas.push(para);
      }
    });
});

let partnumber = 0;
for (const para of sortedParas) {
    partnumber++
    if (para.innerHTML === '') {
        para.innerHTML = partnumber;
    }
};
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/_rjxnZCHs